# jQuery plugin Infinite Ajax Scroll call document.write function after loading items

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, scroll, infinite-scroll

I use a jQuery plugin [Infinite Ajax Scroll](https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll) for loading items on scroll.

The problem is that I have an snippet like this:

```
<div class="availib"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(getAvailabilityString("[Producer]"));</script></div>
```

Here I create an availability string for each item.

My load on scroll function:

```
jQuery.ias({
        container : '#itemcontainer',
        item: '.row',
        pagination: ".resultC .next",
        next: ".resultC .next a",
        loader: '<img src="/layout/cyt/img/pageloader.gif">',
        history: false,
        triggerPageThreshold: 20,
        trigger: "Mehr Artikel laden",
        thresholdMargin: -600,
        onRenderComplete: function(items) {
                           //someCode
                    }
});
```

I have tried to call the snippet `onRenderComplete` but it does not work.
I am thinking about an alternative, but at the moment I have absolutely no idea how to fix this.